# Nodej.s routing with express.js and TypeScript

Tags: node.js, typescript, express, typeorm

I have question about node.js routes. Which routing version is correct?
First version it's a standard version in express.js:

```
router.get('/packages/:name', (req, res) => {
//my example code
);
```

Second version with TypeScript. This version is from typeorm init command.

```
export const Routes = [{
    method: "post",
    route: "/user",
    controller: CustomerController,
    action: "createUser"
}];
```

Which version is better and why? About the second version, how i can add custom middleware? What is difference between first and second version?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Both the approaches are same. When you have a lot of routes for a single point like `root/apiv1/[here all the routes]` then the second 
  one is preferable, if you have many dynamic routes, so its better to 
  go with the first approach.
- Talking about the language, you can achieve both kind of routing in
  plane JS and also in JS. But due to typecasting and validations,
  preferred language is typescript and way of routing depends on the situation.
- Talking about the middleware, for the first approach we will pass the
  middleware just before the controller function, and for the second
  approach, we are bascially creating  structures for our routes and we need to
  pass these routes to some `route()` end point, there we will
  define the middleware just like we are doing in the first approach.

Comment: Thank you very much for answer :) Now i understand :)